# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

I have a page of posts. I added an edit icon so that when I click on it, it should show me the edit page. However, when I click, it displays an error.

**Blade/Form**

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('post.update', 
    ['id'=>$post->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('post/edit/{id}', 'PostController@edit')
    ->name('post.edit');
```

The following is the `edit()` method inside the PostController.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$post` isn't null? Try using `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`, which will 404 if that ID doesn't return a record. You can use `dd($post)` within your controller or `@dd($post)` inside your view to see what is actually being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `findOrFail` to throw a 404 if you pass an id that doesn't exist.

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.edit')->with('post', $post);
}
```

or bind the model in the route

```php
Route::get('post/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit');
```

```php
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution but i get 404 | Not Found, it's like the `$post` is null, but I have 2 posts, because i have a view called index, it shows all the posts for the user I'm login in with, then i click on edit icon and it displays 404, so I think that I have a problem on the index view

Comment: What happens if you add `dd(Post::get());` in your controller? Do you get both posts? What about their ids?

Comment: I added `dd(Post::get());` in the `index()` method and i get the two posts with their ids
This is one of  The Post element on it's array:
`#attributes: array:9 [▼
"id" => 8
"user_id" => 1
"title" => "streets"
"content" => "blablablablablablablablablablablablablabla"
"photo" => "uploads/posts/1608063920bg-prgm-wall_1.jpg"
"slug" => "streets"
"deleted_at" => null
"created_at" => "2020-12-15 20:25:20"
"updated_at" => "2020-12-15 20:25:20"
]`

Comment: And these ids are the same you end with in the url?

Comment: Yes it looks like this:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit/id?9`
And I think the url should be like this:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit/9`

Comment: Oww, When I wrote the url like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit/9` it works and it show the edit view, but when I go back to the view of all posts(index) and click to the icon to edit it it displays the same error, so I think the problem on the icon click on index view,  this the icon code: `<a class="text-warning" href="{{route('post.edit',['id',$item->id])}}"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-edit"></i></a>`

Comment: I found out where was the problem, I should of replace the `,` with `=>`, on this code: `['id',$item->id]` to be like this `['id'=>$item->id]`.
thanks bro for your help, now I figured it out because of you

Comment: Glad you figured it out.